# C: Different value every time program is run

Tags: c, arrays

I have a simple function in C to get whether an array is sorted, but I seem to be getting different values every time. Sometimes I get 3 tests passed and sometimes I get 2 tests passed and am unsure what the problem is.

```
int is_sorted(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        if(a[i] > a[i + 1])
        {   
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1; 
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2, 4, 9, 8, 12};
    int b[] = {-5, -2, 0, 8, 11, 15};
    int aa[] = {2, 18, 12, 9, 1, 2, 8, 11, 16, 3};
    int c[] = {4, 6, 8, 10};

    npassed = 0;
    if(!is_sorted(a, 5)) 
    {
        npassed++;
    }
    if(is_sorted(b, 6)) 
    {
        npassed++;
    }
    if(!is_sorted(aa, 10)) 
    {
        npassed++;
    }
    if(is_sorted(c, 5)) 
    {
      npassed++;
    }
    printf("number passed is_sorted  :  %i\n", npassed);
}
```

Comment: `if(a[i] > a[i + 1])` may go past the end of the array

Comment: it surely goes past in this case: `is_sorted(c, 5)`

Comment: also, where's `npassed` declaration?

Comment: I was playing with it and yea I just saw a problem with `if(a[i] > a[i + 1])`, and also the call for `is_sorted(c, 5)`. It seems that the problem is gone after that.

Comment: Count the number of elements in the arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function accepts two arguments:

- `a`: the array
- `n`: the arrays size

to check if it is sorted you iterate over all elements and see if its next element is bigger than itself. To do that, you count with `i` from zero (the lowest possible index) to `n-1` (the highest possible index).

But you always check if `i` is greater than `i+1`. And what happens if you reach the last possible index for `i`? Then `i+1` is equal to `n` and therefore outside the array. And what's outside your array is random data.